# How do you set the default speaker on Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have tried `pactl list short sink`, but I get

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

which leads me to believe that ubuntu is using a different audio management technology now. Is this correct? What is the proper way to set the default speaker in focal?

Comment: apparently one has to go to home with the terminal and modify a bash file with nano .bashrc however further instructions would be appreaciated since I am afraid of breaking something.

Comment: @JaimeAvalos Where did you find that information? We might be able to figure it out with further details.

Comment: Type `dmesg` and check for errors related to sound / audio. If you find some post them into your question. Also shorten the command to `pactl list short`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe running this command with sudo could work?

Comment: Programs will tell you when `sudo` is required or will print an error like `permission denied`.

Comment: Often yes, but I had sometimes this kind of errors and using sudo it gone